# Need php form to name which required fields have not been filled out

Tags: php, forms

My php form has required fields, but the message does not let the user know which field hasn't been entered. How can I do this?

```
//if statement to check required fields
if ($name && $phone && $email && && $address && $city && $state && $zip && $month && $date && $year && $contact)...
    //if some required fields were not filled out
    echo "Please make sure you fill in all required fields<br>Click <a href=\"javascript:history.back(1)\">here</a> to return to our form.";
}
```

Comment: Uhm... are these variables just examples, or have you created them from the `$_POST` array (plus maybe some filtering and/or validation) or - beware - have you enabled `register_globals`?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a trivial example...

```
// An array of required fields, these fields must not be empty
$requiredFields = array('name', 'email');  

// Iterate through required fields
foreach ($requiredFields as $fieldName)
{
    // Does this field have a value?
    if (empty($_REQUEST[$fieldName]))
    {
        echo 'rawr! go back and fill out ' . $fieldName . "<br>\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like each of those are boolean values; I assume you set them earlier when checking each value individually. Instead of using a single `echo` at the end, I would initialize a `$message` variable at the beginning, and put all error messages there. At the end, just `echo $message'`.

Answer (score 0):

Just tedious if/else clauses. You could use a validation framework to elemiate alot of this.

```
if (empty($name))
   echo "Name is not filled out";
if(empty($phone))
   echo "Phone is not filled out";
```

If you want to get fancy this would work

```
foreach (array("name","phone") as $var)
{
   if (empty($$name))
      echo "$var is not filled out";
}
```